# Extracting names from the data frame as separate data in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, stringr

I have a sample data frame with name and surname. I need to extract names as separate data. I had the idea to do this one by one for each name, but the data set is large and I need a faster way. Can you help me?

```
df<-data.frame(name = c("John Smith", "Antonio Gilbert", "Rickie Hooley", "John Marquez", "Christian Thompson", "Rickie Galvan"),
           telephone = c("234324", "2342343", "547547", "68656486", "5686686", "4664546"))

John <- df[grep("John", df$name), 1]
Rickie <- df[grep("Rickie", df$name), 1]
```

Comment: No, I want to select all the lines with the given name.

Comment: Suppose I have a thousand people including a hundred John's and I need a separate data frame with all John's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce a list of dataframes, each containing one of the different first names.  You can access them with `dflist$John` etc.

```
firstnames <- unique(gsub("\\s.*$", "", df$name))

dflist <- lapply(firstnames, function(x) df[grep(x, df$name), 1, drop = FALSE])

names(dflist) <- firstnames

dflist
$John
          name
1   John Smith
4 John Marquez

$Antonio
             name
2 Antonio Gilbert

$Rickie
           name
3 Rickie Hooley
6 Rickie Galvan

$Christian
                name
5 Christian Thompson
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate dataframes based on their name, we can first extract the first name and then `split` on them.

```
output <- split(df, sub("\\s.*", "", df$name))
output

#$Antonio
#             name telephone
#2 Antonio Gilbert   2342343

#$Christian
#                name telephone
#5 Christian Thompson   5686686

#$John
#          name telephone
#1   John Smith    234324
#4 John Marquez  68656486

#$Rickie
#           name telephone
#3 Rickie Hooley    547547
#6 Rickie Galvan   4664546
```

So now you have list of dataframes which can be accessed by `output$Antonio`, `output$Christian` and so on.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I need separate data for each name. For example: > df1 %>% filter(grepl("John", name)), > df2 %>% filter(grepl("Rickie", name))

Comment: @Zizou I have updated the answer based on that. Can you check now?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `group_split` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_split(nameGroup = str_remove(name, "\\s.*"))
```